# Debugging Using Emacs 24 and IPython breakpoint

Tags: python, debugging, emacs, ipython, pdb

I have right now shifted from Pycharm to Emacs. Just wanted to use Emacs. Right now the major hurdle is debugging using pdb. I am really afraid of import pdb; pdb.set_trace(). Last time I tried this way of debugging using SublimeText and was ended many pdb.set_trace() in code. Now as I am moving to Emacs, I am looking for someway.

1. Best practices
2. Is there any way in Emacs, that I can open some buffer only for debugging and dont save it. Instead I changes other copy which I will save.
3. Is there any way to debug any unsaved buffer in Emacs.

Kinldy guide me thanks.
Noaman Faisal

Comment: Good question, maybe follow up there: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1248657